# TU Munich Monocular Visual Odometry Dataset has NaN values in the ground truth data.

Tags: computer-vision, visual-odometry, monocular

I am trying to use the motion sequences in the dataset to create trajectories for VR systems. A major portion of the ground truth data in almost all sequences has NaN values. Is there any other source with the correct values?

Or is any other good monocular visual odometry dataset with various motion sequences included available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [webpage](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/mono-dataset) for the dataset:

> All sequences contain mostly exploring camera motion, starting and ending at the same position: this allows to evaluate tracking accuracy via the accumulated drift from start to end, without requiring ground-truth for the full sequence.

It appears as though they didn't intend the ground truth for these datasets to be complete.

For monocular odometry data with complete ground truth data, you could try [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php).

Answer (score 2):

NaN values are sometimes used to indicate unavailable data. Is it possible that these are simply portions of the dataset for which ground truth was not available, but you can still evaluate on the remainder of the sequence (and that this is in fact the standard evaluation domain)? It looks like their evaluation code checks for trajectory entries with any NaNs and ignores them with a warning.

Comment: Yes. I just went through the webpage which mentions that they do not have the ground-truth for the whole sequence. Unfortunately, the rest of the sequence for which ground-truth is available did not contain any useful motion sequences that I could extract.